# Android Transitions (API 19) - How to setText() on TextView before transition?

Tags: android, android-transitions

I am animating a TextView using android's API19 transitions. I defined a scene that i wish to transition to:

`scene = Scene.getSceneForLayout(rootLayout, R.layout.my_scene, this);`

I defined my transition:

`myTransition = new ChangeBounds();
myTransition.setDuration(1000);
myTransition.setInterpolator(new BounceInterpolator());`

And I begin transition:

`TransitionManager.go(scene, myTransition);`

Everything works as long as I have the `android:text` hardcoded. Here is what `my_scene.xml` looks like:

```
<merge xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
<TextView
        android:id="@+id/textview1"
        android:layout_width="100dp"
        android:layout_height="100dp"
        android:text="text1"/>
</merge>
```

An identical TextView with the same id is in `activity_main.xml`, but in a different position.
When I try to set the text dynamically using `setText()` it will not change the text. I am not very experienced with this transition API so any help is appreciated.

Comment: Try the onStart listener, find the TextView and setText https://developer.android.com/reference/android/transition/Transition.TransitionListener.html#onTransitionStart(android.transition.Transition)

Comment: There is no reason at all why setting the text should not work. Are you really sure you are setting the right string as text on the correct `TextView`?

Answer (score 3):

Define the scene enter action and then call the go() method in TransitionManager.  Here is the code snippet

```
   scene = Scene.getSceneForLayout(rootLayout, R.layout.my_scene, this); scene.setEnterAction(new Runnable() {
    @Override
    public void run() {
      TextView textView1 = (TextView)rootLayout.findViewById(R.id.textView1);
      textView1.setText("Hello World");
    }
  }); TransitionManager.go(scene, myTransition);
```

Answer (score 0):

What if you try to delay the transition via the `TextView`'s event queue?

```
final Scene scene = Scene.getSceneForLayout(rootLayout, R.layout.my_scene, this);
final ChangeBounds myTransition = new ChangeBounds();
myTransition.setDuration(1000);
myTransition.setInterpolator(new BounceInterpolator());

TextView tv;
tv.setText("Some text");


tv.post(new Runnable() {
    @Override
    public void run() {
        TransitionManager.go(scene, myTransition);
    }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

You may try having an initial scene by initializing a Scene variable scene one and using enter() to set the initial scene.

Then, you can transition from scene1 to scene2, your target scene. Above that, I've also noticed some lag during the change of text from scene1 to scene2. In order to counteract that, I utilized the TransitionListener class to detect when the scene was finished transitioning. Then, I altered the text using setText() after the transition.